# How do I troubleshoot my computer not suspending automatically?

Tags: suspend

I can use suspend without any problem if I do it manually. It resumes OK as well.

However, for some reason it has stopped doing this automatically. Right now it is set to suspend after 30 minutes but it can be idle for hours without suspending.

Answer (score 1):

I would check for any USB devices such as mouses, keyboards, or WLAN adapters... or even a NIC card might be causing it not to sleep... what you could do is set your suspend to 5 mins or something, and eliminate each one, till it works... if it works then you know that device is the cause... if it doesn't work then maybe someone else might have an idea... I have never had this issue on Ubuntu, but I have had it on Windows.... and this is the method I use to troubleshoot it.